# Quando usar "excluir" ao analisar "Publicações de Baixa Qualidade"?

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise, qualidade

Na fila de análise "Publicações de Baixa Qualidade" tem muitos itens esperando para serem revisados, e gostaria de contribuir, mas não estou muito certo **como**. Noto que existe um botão "Excluir" e, ao clicá-lo, diversas opções de comentário "*boilerplate*" aparecem (aliás, ainda não traduzidos - mas acho que alguém ja reportou isso), e noto que algum outro usuário já a utilizou (pois na resposta está o comentário proposto *ipsis litteris*).

O que devo fazer? (assumindo que minha análise independente chegue à mesma conclusão de um outro avaliador)

- Usar o botão "excluir", marcando o radio "Nenhum comentário é necessário";
- Usar o botão "excluir", marcando o mesmo comentário que o outro usuário já fez;

  - Isso faria o comentário ser postado de novo? Não teria nenhum efeito? Daria +1 no comentário existente? Ajudaria os moderadores a tomar uma decisão?
- **Não usar** o botão "excluir" **a menos** que a resposta seja uma "causa perdida" e tenha mesmo que ser removida (quando concordo com uma análise de post de baixa qualidade, é porque o post realmente me parece ter baixa qualidade... mas não estou certo se é o caso de excluir).

Comment: Sei lá. Excluir é algo extremo e acho que só deveria ser usado para as causas perdidas. Para o resto, o votar contra e o fechar (se for uma pergunta) acho que deveriam ser o suficiente.

Comment: @Victor, a maioria é resposta, são curtas, o próprio sistema sinaliza como baixa qualidade. Até agora estamos deixando passar, mas vamos ter que começar tomar providência logo. A maioria deveria virar comentário. Temos que deixar claro que respostas devem ser respostas de verdade. Sei que muita gente vai espernear, falar que é resposta sim, vai dizer que até um "sim" é uma resposta. Mas temos nosso conceito de resposta verdadeiro. Vamos precisar formalizar tudo isso e mostrar para os novatos no **nosso** site. Depois disso, quem não entender, paciência.

Comment: Eu espero que o Gabe esteja vendo essas sinalizações como pedidos de transformação em comentário, pelo menos em muitos casos é isso que deve-se fazer.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, poderia ver meus comentários na resposta abaixo?

Comment: @Math Se você se refere ao título da pergunta, concordo com a sugestão, alterei.

Comment: Exatamente isso, obrigado, acho que ficou muito mais claro agora.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meu critério para decidir quando usar o botão de excluir (ou recomendar exclusão – ver rodapé da resposta) é o seguinte: votar para excluir somente quando quando o conteúdo não acrescenta nenhuma informação útil e seja uma "causa perdida", como você disse. Exemplos:

- Resposta do autor da pergunta para agradecer aos que o ajudaram.
- Pergunta em forma de resposta (outra pergunta do próprio autor, ou de outra pessoa).
- "Respostas" do tipo "estou com o mesmo problema, alguém conseguiu resolver?".

Em todos esses casos, também é recomendável deixar um comentário explicando o motivo, caso alguém ainda não tenha feito isso. A parte chata é que muitas vezes o autor não terá a chance de ver esse comentário, caso não tenha um link para a pergunta. Se não me engano, somente comentários feitos por moderadores continuam a gerar notificações mesmo depois do post ter sido excluído. Mesmo assim, sou da opinião de que esse tipo de ruído deve ser removido do site com agilidade.

Tome cuidado nos seguintes casos:

- Respostas que deveriam ser comentários (geralmente de usuários sem permissão para comentar). Como o bigown comentou acima, muitas vezes esse tipo de resposta deve ser convertida em comentário por um moderador. Porém, se o mesmo questionamento já tiver sido feito por outra pessoa, pode-se votar para excluir (o critério é o que já mencionei acima: o conteúdo não acrescenta nada de útil).
- Respostas que contenham somente links. Embora essa seja uma das opções do diálogo de adicionar comentário antes de votar, geralmente essas respostas são indicativas de uma pergunta que precisa ser fechada (por ser vaga, ampla demais, ou por pedir opiniões ou recomendações). Os critérios e regras no SOpt para se lidar com esse tipo de pergunta e resposta ainda não estão 100% claros. Quando possível, visite o link e edite a resposta para incluir um pequeno resumo do conteúdo, ou deixe um comentário pedindo que o autor faça isso. Se é uma resposta antiga, que já tem um comentário do tipo mas foi abandonada pelo autor, pode ser o caso de votar para excluir. Em outros casos, um moderador pode converter a resposta em comentário para que ela gere menos ruído, sem prejuízo do conteúdo que possa acrescentar.
- Respostas incorretas. Raramente é o caso de excluí-las. Se a resposta está errada, merece um voto contra, não ser excluídas. Isso vale também para respostas que *tentam* responder a pergunta, mas erram o alvo devido a um mau-entendimento da mesma.

Essa fila de análise tem ainda um problema na interface: a opção "parece bom" pode soar confusa. O objetivo é dizer que a postagem pode ficar como está, mas muitos interpretam como uma manifestação de apoio ao que está dito ali, o que não é o caso. Se você quer apoiar a postagem, abra a pergunta e dê um voto a favor.

Quanto às suas outras dúvidas:

> Usar o botão "excluir", marcando o radio "Nenhum comentário é necessário"

Faço isso quando já existem comentários suficientes explicando o problema (e, claro, a postagem se encaixe nos critérios de exclusão que já citei).

> Usar o botão "excluir", marcando o mesmo comentário que o outro usuário já fez;
>   Isso faria o comentário ser postado de novo?

Não.

> Não teria nenhum efeito? Daria +1 no comentário existente?

*Acho* que daria +1

> Ajudaria os moderadores a tomar uma decisão?

Se eles virem o post, talvez.

Vale também uma olhada em [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029) (em inglês)

---

**Nota**

Votos para excluir e recomendar exclusão funcionam da seguinte maneira:

- A maioria dos usuários verá a opção de "recomendar exclusão". [6 recomendações apagam a postagem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145292/167534).
- Usuários com o privilégio de acesso às ferramentas de moderação podem votar para excluir em casos bastante específicos (não tenho certeza, mas acho que em respostas com pontuação negativa e pelo menos 2 dias de existência). O número diário de votos por usuário é limitado.
- Usuários com o privilégio de usuário confiável podem votar para excluir respostas com pontuação negativa (se bem que na fila de análise podem votar para excluir qualquer resposta). O número diário de votos por usuário é limitado.
- 3 votos para excluir apagam a postagem.

Comment: Não existe (mais ?) o botão `Excluir`, ele foi trocado pelo `Fechar`?

Comment: Em perguntas, o botão é fechar @Math. Só podem ser excluídas perguntas já fechadas.

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, mas acho que acabei de votar errado [nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5830), rsrs.. Eu quis dizer q parecia boa pois ainda existia salvação para ela e eu apenas não queria que ela fosse excluída, mas o certo era eu ter votado para fechar. Nunca tinha votado em uma questão do tipo baixa qualidade antes, talvez poderia ressaltar na sua resposta que o botão fechar e o botão excluir são coisas muito distintas pois acabei me confundindo por não ver nenhum botão Excluir na pergunta. Achei que por estarmos em beta talvez tivessem trocado.

Comment: @Math Não manjo de crystal reports, mas a resposta existente parece responder o que está sendo perguntado. Será mesmo que é pra fechar como "não está claro..."?

Comment: Ok.. talvez eu tenha cometido dois equivocos então, que resultou em um acerto. Talvez nosso comentários aqui já sejam o suficiente para ajudar alguém que teve a mesma dúvida que eu, pois o que eu quis dizer é q o botão Excluir nem sempre está visível, e isso pode ser confuso para alguém que vai fazer sua primeira análise de post de baixa qualidade.

Comment: Ou talvez o título da pergunta deveria ser: `Quando devo votar para excluir uma pergunta da fila de baixa qualidade?` Pois é o único assunto tratado aqui, e eu vim aqui para aprender a votar em publicações de baixa qualidade no geral, o que me levou a confusão que eu citei acima. De qualquer forma sua resposta foi muito útil.

Comment: @Math Eu não tenho certeza, mas acho que não dá para excluir perguntas nessa fila. Acho que ela só mostra perguntas abertas, e para ser excluída a pergunta precisa estar fechada. Vou tentar completar a resposta outra hora, ando meio sem tempo...