# Esta resposta merece ser excluída?

Tags: debate, voto-contra, exclusão

[Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8380/74) me chamou a atenção [na fila](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5618) de publicações de baixa qualidade. Ela é incorreta, mas é uma tentativa de responder à pergunta. Merece ser excluída? Quatro pessoas acharam que sim. [Eu acho que não](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/695), merece apenas votos contra.

O que vocês acham, e por quê?

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: [Qual a maneira correta de analisar “Publicações de Baixa Qualidade”?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/662/215) Concordo com você (tanto lá quanto aqui) que essa resposta **não** merece ser excluída.

Comment: Aquele `E agora?` final é bastante estranho, *"E agora o quê, cara pálida?!"* Acho que merece mais votos contra e a medalha "Peer pressure" quando o próprio autor deletar o post.

Comment: Pra mim parece mais com um comentário do que com uma resposta propriamente dita.

Comment: De acordo com suas próprias palavras: `votar para excluir somente quando quando o conteúdo não acrescenta nenhuma informação útil e seja uma "causa perdida"`. Acho que é o caso da resposta citada.

Comment: @Renan Isso está dentro do contexto maior da minha resposta, onde também digo: *Respostas incorretas. Raramente é o caso de excluí-las. Se a resposta está errada, merece um voto contra, não ser excluídas. Isso vale também para respostas que tentam responder a pergunta, mas erram o alvo devido a um mau-entendimento da mesma.*

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Essa impressão é por causa do tom da resposta, não exatamente do conteúdo. Se ela dissesse "Coloque este script no topo do seu html e altere o form assim: [código]", você teria a mesma impressão?

Comment: Ler essa resposta me deu desânimo, sério. #desabafo

Comment: @bfavaretto, não, mas daí, provavelmente, a resposta estaria correta e não pareceria uma opinião (comentário) como parece.

Answer (score 4):

É claramente uma resposta do tipo 'Eu não tenho como garantir que irá funcionar para você; faça um teste, e nos diga se funcionou de acordo com sua expectativa.' Eu mesmo já respondi várias perguntas com este estilo de resposta.

Também é, claramente, de baixa qualidade.

Merece os pontos negativos, mas não está tão fora de escopo a ponto de merecer exclusão.

Answer (score 2):

Minha opinião é comum à sua. É votar contra e adicionar comentários para que a pessoa que respondeu melhore a resposta e de quebra aprenda a responder melhor e servindo de exemplo para outras pessoas responderem.

Só excluir não ajudaria outras pessoas a responderem melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Eu creio que a resposta deveria ser um comentário devido ao tom e teor.

A pergunta se refere a uma dúvida do OP com relação a navegação de uma tela para outra de um sistema. A resposta contém algum código, e até pouco antes da frase final parece apenas uma resposta errada. Ênfase em **parece**. Após ler a última frase, minha interpretação da resposta, resumidamente, é a seguinte:

> "O que acontece se você recarregar a página atual?"

Minha impressão é reforçada pelos comentários que seguem a resposta (i.e.: "pois eu tenho outra ideia").

Entendo que seria um tanto mais complicado colocar o código de recarga em um comentário, mas isso não justifica que o comentário seja postado em formato de resposta.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta é, na melhor das interpretações, **incompleta**. Tanto antes quanto depois da edição. Ela apresenta trechos de código sem nenhuma explicação sobre como eles se aplicariam ao problema, ou que raciocínio existe por trás deles.

Sob muitos aspectos o SOPT funciona como seu local de trabalho. No trabalho você pode dar uma pescoçada e pedir ajuda pra quem está do seu lado e aqui você pode fazer o mesmo. Só que pra mil pessoas, ao invés de uma só. Isso não significa que a interação aqui vai funcionar **exatamete** como funcionaria com alguém do seu lado.

## "Por quê?"

Imagine que essa pergunta foi feita ao vivo... Eu imagino que o diálogo correria assim, mais ou menos:

*"Como eu faço pra retornar pra essa página com os dados que eu salvei?"*
*"Coloca esse javascript aqui...*
*"Funcionou! **Por quê?***

Quase ninguém no mundo vai falar "Funcionou!" e virar as costas, dando-se por satisfeita. Entender **como** as coisas funcionam é talvez ainda mais importante que simplesmente saber que elas funcionam.

A interação entre duas pessoas aqui no SOPT **deve** seguir esse padrão mas, obviamente, sem que você precise perguntar como aquilo funciona *depois* de fazer funcionar.

É por isso que essa resposta, e todas as outras no passado, presente e futuro como ela, parecem incompleta. Se uma resposta te deixa com um "Como assim?" na cabeça, não é uma boa resposta. Não há problema em dar uma resposta errada, desde que ela esteja errada de forma *completa*.

## Contexto

Feita essa análise *crua* sobre o que eu vejo na respota, um pouco de contexto (e suco de laranja, não fazem mal a ninguém. Logo antes de escrever a resposta, o @SamirBraga deixou [um comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8379/voltar-para-a-tela-anterior-apos-cadastro-usando-kohana/8380#comment14246_8379):

> Um comando para dar um refresh serveria? – **Samir Braga** 6/03 às 22:27

E obteve [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8379/voltar-para-a-tela-anterior-apos-cadastro-usando-kohana/8380#comment14248_8379):

> SIm sim, acredito que sim, pelo menos eu acho – **Daniel Swater** 6/03 às 22:29

Além disso, tudo isso ocorreu quando a reposta [ainda não tinha um monte de código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/8379/1) explicando um pouco melhor o problema.

Olhando a pergunta no seu estado atual, com uma resposta já aceita, e ver a resposta do @SamirBraga lá causa uma grande estranheza, de ela está completamente deslocada e não ajuda em nada. Mas aquela resposta é filha de um contexto diferente do atual. É importante manter isso em mente quando você for avaliar a relevância de qualquer post no site. Isso já aconteceu comigo no Arqade, e a resposta foi removida.

## Errar não é crime

Respostas não devem ser apagadas (nem sinalizadas, diga-se de passagem) **só** porque são erradas. Se alguém apresentar uma solução que não resolve o problema, ou usa uma técnica defasada, ou qualquer outro motivo que a torne *tecnicamente incorreta*, vote contra. Talvez deixe um comentário explicando o motivo da rejeição. É besteira pensar que uma resposta errada não ajuda em nada. Ela serve de mau exemplo.

Não é brincadeira... Ver algo errado, e entender porque é errado, pode não ser tão útil quanto aprender o correto mas certamente é valioso. Ver uma resposta com -3 pontos mostrando algo que você teria feito também te ensina. Não há necessidade de se remover uma resposta ou comentário **só** porque ele é errado.

## Mas nesse caso...

Especificamente falando, eu não tenho problema com a exclusão dessa resposta. Da forma atual, ela é descontextualizada e acrescenta muito pouco (seja como bom ou mau exemplo) para quem lê a pergunta. Os comentários dela são indicativos do que eu estou falando... Depois que o @SamirBraga pediu um esclarimento maior sobre o problema e o autor acrescentou o código à pergunta (e respondeu), os dois pararam de conversar nos comentários e começaram a aparecer os comentários "criticando" a resposta.

A resposta é um produto de circunstâncias que não existem mais e se tornou inválida, e por isso eu não vejo problema em apagar.

Comment: Eu concordo com muito do que você disse, mas não tenho certeza sobre a conclusão. Não ter problema com a exclusão é uma coisa. Eu também não ligo para a falta dessa resposta. Mas será que sempre que uma resposta ficar assim fora de contexto a comunidade deve excluí-la? Eu, se fosse o autor da resposta, excluiria logo após a edição da pergunta. O autor da resposta em questão provavelmente excluiu após os downvotes. Minha dúvida é se cabe à comunidade esse tipo de exclusão.

Comment: @bfavaretto Acredito que sim. Mas isso depende dos parâmetros que eu falei. Se eu vir uma resposta fora de contexto, o melhor é realmente removê-la. Não é o caso para uma resposta que está **errada**.