# Vocês acham isso certo?

Tags: debate, respostas

[image: Descrição da imagem]

Denunciaram [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/360427/112052), e após isso alguém respondeu a mesma coisa. Me senti completamente injustiçado com isso, acho que quem tem que analisar se a resposta é útil ou não é a pessoa que perguntou. Espero que isso não ocorra mais, aqui é pra todos aprendermos e não ganhar pontos pra elevar ego.

Observações:
A pergunta foi minha, e mesmo depois da pergunta eu continuei a tentar alternativas no meu código, então eu encontrei, como não havia respostas ainda, decidi responder, pois caso alguém com a mesma dúvida aparecesse estaria já a resposta ali.

Comment: Se é certo ou não, eu não sei, mas relatar/reclamar de uma pergunta/resposta e não postar o link dela para que possamos entender melhor o caso indo ao post, não me parece nada certo.

Comment: Eu não acho. Deixei o meu comentário na resposta do Maniero.

Comment: É bom tb explicar o motivo de usar uma coisa ou outra. Só falar "use isto " em vez "disso" acaba fazendo com que a resposta pareça um chute (mesmo que esteja correta), ainda mais sendo curta.

Answer (score 22):

Eu sou um dos que votaram para remover a resposta. Ao contrário do que alguns podem pensar, eu não fiz de maneira "automática", "mecanizada" e "sem pensar". Usei um critério que explico logo abaixo. O problema é que, lendo os comentários aqui, percebi que talvez meu critério não esteja de acordo com o que a comunidade espera. Então vamos lá:

---

### Meu critério para remoção

Quando a resposta apareceu para análise, podemos ver [no histórico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/360427/revisions) que ela [estava assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/86dc0733-36ff-4369-8fe2-3bbcfe21c729/view-source):

```
é só usar no lugar do swapAdapter(adapter, true) setAdapter(adapter)
```

Somente este texto, nada mais. Mesmo que dê para entender, é o tipo de resposta que queremos no site?

Para mim, o grande diferencial do Stack Overflow (tanto em português quanto em inglês) sempre foram as respostas detalhadas, que não só mostram o código, mas também explicam porque aquilo funciona, qual o conceito por trás daquilo, porque do outro jeito não funciona, etc.

O fato do site incentivar este tipo de resposta (por meio do *gamification*) também é algo que sempre considerei positivo. Não só incentivar as respostas boas, mas não incentivar as ruins também. Pelo menos essa era a minha ideia do site, e por isso abomino respostas do tipo *"Tente isso: (código jogado sem contexto nem explicação)"*.

A resposta que foi removida eu considero que é do tipo que só tem código (*"tente isso: (código)"* e *"troque esse código por esse"*, sem nenhuma explicação adicional, para mim é a mesma coisa).

Se tivesse ao menos uma explicação, por menor que fosse, tornaria a resposta um pouco melhor. Por que trocar um método por outro? Por que o primeiro não funcionou? Ou ele só funciona neste caso, ou em alguns contextos, ou dependendo do caso o certo é usar um ou outro? etc...

Qualquer explicação nesse sentido tornaria a resposta útil para futuros visitantes (não é isso que vivemos dizendo, que as respostas devem ser úteis não só para o AP, mas para qualquer outro que visite o site futuramente?)

O fato do próprio autor da pergunta ter respondido é irrelevante. Por acaso devemos adotar critérios de qualidade diferentes quando o próprio autor da pergunta responde? A recomendação não é a de que devemos olhar o conteúdo e não a pessoa? Se qualquer um tivesse escrito uma resposta daquela, eu votaria para remover também.

> "Ahá, e por que você não removeu a outra resposta?"

Porque eu não vi, simples assim. Eu não fico 24 horas por dia no site, e com certeza deixo passar muita coisa. Infelizmente há mais perguntas a serem fechadas e respostas a serem negativadas/apagadas do que pessoas dispostas a fazê-lo. Mas eu votaria para remover a outra também, pois é uma resposta só com código e sem nenhum contexto ou explicação. E não precisa escrever um livro/artigo, basta uma explicação simples para que a resposta melhore.

Esse é o meu critério. Mas pelo que li das outras respostas e comentários aqui, não parece ser o critério correto para remover respostas. O que eu deveria ter feito é dado um voto negativo e/ou comentado, pois a remoção é um exagero. O que me leva a outra questão...

---

### Filas de análise e *mea culpa*

Quando ganhei acesso à [fila de Publicações de baixa qualidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) (que é onde ocorreu a análise da resposta em questão), não recebi instruções de como proceder. Até procurei, e vi que no [FAQ do meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) não existe esta informação.

Na própria tela da análise, só diz:

> **Recomendar exclusão** recomendar a remoção da resposta

Mas não diz nada sobre os critérios.

Na Central de Ajuda, a única referência que encontrei sobre esta fila é na página que explica o [privilégio de edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). O texto que tem lá é esse:

> Além da revisão de edições sugeridas, a fila de [publicações de baixa qualidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) também é disponibilizada. Essa fila contém publicações que foram consideradas de baixa qualidade pelo sistema. Os usuários são encarregados da tarefa de editar para melhorar o formato e o conteúdo, recomendando a exclusão do que não deveria estar em nosso site ou indicando que se trata de uma publicação aceitável.

Novamente, nenhuma explicação sobre o critério para considerar "*o que não deveria estar em nosso site*".

A única referência que encontrei foi [essa pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/662/112052), cuja resposta aceita possui um link para o [FAQ do meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/401803). Ambos recomendam que, em casos de respostas como a que foi removida, devemos melhorá-la via edição e/ou deixar um comentário e/ou dar um voto negativo.

Por um tempo eu até segui esta recomendação, mas ela se mostrou infrutífera. Ao editar uma resposta que só tem código, ela continua sendo uma resposta que só tem código (e que para mim, é uma resposta ruim, como já expliquei acima). E na grande maioria dos casos, comentar e negativar não adianta muito, pois quase sempre você é ignorado. Nas poucas vezes em que não fui ignorado, o autor da resposta se irritou, discordando do comentário, ou editou mas sem melhorar nada, e algumas vezes até xingou/esbravejou. São raros os casos em que o *post* é de fato melhorado, e isso é muito frustrante. Depois de um tempo cansei disso e passei a simplesmente votar para remover tais respostas.

E este é o critério que tenho usado desde então. Mas pelo que vi nos outros comentários e respostas daqui, eu não deveria votar para remover tais postagens.

Bom, se tudo bem para a comunidade este tipo de resposta permanecer no site, então peço desculpas pelo transtorno causado. Todas as análises que faço é para manter a qualidade geral do site, pois acredito que as filas de análise são uma ferramenta importante para isso.

Mas se a forma como tenho analisado está prejudicando o site, então me digam, que mudarei minha postura nas filas de análise sem problemas. Mas se não há uma diretriz clara (apenas opiniões sobre como proceder), então continuarei votando para remover.

Comment: +1 Pelo menos você é coerente, e tem a noção que as duas respostas são idênticas no conteúdo. Foi exatamente por isso que eu vim aqui comentar. Pelo que sei, só se deve remover respostas quando elas não forem mesmo respostas. Neste caso não deixa de ser uma resposta, claro que falta alguma formatação e alguma explicação, talvez, mas é para isso que existem os negativos e os comentários. Eu percebo a sua frustração, mas a ideia é tentar sempre melhorar o conteúdo. (continua)

Comment: Que vantagem tem remover respostas incompletas? É que o ser incompleto é bem subjetivo. Eu lembro-me de uma resposta que eu vi, que por acaso era de um ex professor meu da faculdade e que estava bem incompleta, era só uma linha de código, mas era tão boa essa linha que valia a pena. Vou colocar [aqui o exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/54724/revisions). Veja a primeira versão e depois as outras todas depois de comentários. A meu ver vale sempre a pena agir dessa forma, nem que seja por 1 pessoa que melhore a sua resposta.

Comment: @JorgeB. acredito ser mais um problema da ferramenta. Se ficarmos sinalizando todos estes casos pra moderação, vamos saturar os moderadores com isso sendo que, imagino eu, tenham casos mais importantes pra analisar. A ferramenta, assim como funciona pra eles, deveria ter opção de votar conversão também, assim, o conteudo nao é perdido, apenas migrado pros comentarios.

Comment: @ArticunoL mas eu acho que neste caso é mesmo uma resposta, então o que eu faria era comentar para o AR arranjar a resposta, como no exemplo que eu partilhei. Remover não resolve nada. Porque eu considero isso uma resposta, incompleta mas é uma resposta, não é um comentário.  A ideia do site é editar e não remover conteúdo. Senão para que serviriam os comentários e os pontos negativos?!

Comment: @JorgeB. Admiro sua postura otimista com relação a melhorar respostas, mas depois da experiência frustrante que relatei, não consigo fazer o mesmo. A maioria parece que não se preocupa em melhorar nada. E pelo que vejo, essas respostas que só tem código - e que eu considero ruins - ainda recebem alguns votos positivos (como é o caso da resposta aceita), tornando o meu eventual negativo ainda mais inútil, pois como tem mais positivos, isso passa a mensagem de que este tipo de resposta é bom e aceitável, e que o negativo deve ser de algum "chato que gosta de negativar" ...

Comment: ... Enfim, se a comunidade acha que essas respostas de péssima qualidade devem permanecer no site, mesmo que a maioria nunca seja melhorada, então talvez seja melhor eu dar um tempo nas filas de análise e repensar meus critérios (ou, pelo menos por enquanto, pular esses casos). Se essas respostas recebem votos positivos, talvez eu que seja o errado nessa história, não sei. De qualquer forma, obrigado pelos comentários, é bom conhecer outros pontos de vista :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo mas ai o problema não está no método e sim nas pessoas. Porque se entretanto mudamos o método por causa das pessoas, perde-se a essência do site. Se sempre que aparecer uma pergunta péssima, se em vez de fechar e comentar ou negativar se remover vai perder o sentido das fases anteriores. Pelo menos é o que eu acho. Quanto ao permanecer no site, se elas tiverem negativadas, quem vir saberá que não é uma boa resposta. Mas é uma resposta.

Comment: @hkotsubo você não está errado, errado está quem dá positivo nesse tipo de resposta. Mas a solução, a meu ver, não é apagar o conteúdo. Isso seria como impedir as pessoas de votarem num politico só porque você acha que ele é mau. ;)

Comment: @hkotsubo só para terminar, imagine que essa resposta que você votou para apagar que alguém ia editar e ela ia ficar muito boa, mas como foi apagada nada feito. Entende o ponto onde eu quero chegar? Veja o exemplo que eu dei, se tivessem apagado logo a resposta, nunca teríamos aquela excelente resposta no site. E foi mesmo por isso que eu deixei de analisar filas e responder a perguntas, porque é mesmo frustrante. Não sei de uma solução para esse problema, mas que ele existe, existe.

Answer (score 11):

Em geral respostas colocadas de forma muito simples acabam sendo consideradas comentários. Fica a dica para caprichar um tiquinho mais para evitar isto. Eu acho exagerado considerar não resposta, mas não tiro um pouco a razão de quem votou. Também entendo sua discordância.

Você poderia ter melhorado ela. Mesmo sabendo que não foi bem aceita você restaurou sem melhorar. Isto acaba tirando um pouco sua razão de reclamar, ainda que tenha sido exagerado. Você poderia fazer sua parte e mostrar que teve boa vontade. Quando insiste no mesmo conteúdo começa parecer para muitos como uma birra, mesmo que não seja o que está fazendo. Assim como você quer que olhemos o seu problema, olhe o lado dos demais também.

O fato de você ter aceitado a outra resposta, que pode até ser o mesmo conteúdo, mas está mais caprichada ajuda a mostrar que aceita que a sua é ruim. E note que embora não tenha um prova clara, há indícios que a pessoa sequer copiou a sua resposta, ela só respondeu alguns minutos depois da sua resposta ser removida e ela não vê nada, nem em vermelho. E de fato a dele parece mais completa e clara. Eu entendi pela dele, fiquei perdido lendo a sua resposta. A dele é uma boa resposta, a sua, mesmo que considere como resposta não é boa.

Acho que todos podem aprender com isto.

Comment: De qualquer forma, pelo que sei, não é suposto uma resposta ser removida por isso. Quem removeu também podia ter editado ela e ficaria qualquer coisa como a anterior. Eu não posso concordar com "não é boa" se é praticamente igual à outra só a formatação é que muda, praticamente. Eu entendo que até fosse negativada por estar sem formatação, mas dai a remover. É exatamente o que eu faço no PL, se realmente for uma resposta deixo comentário para melhorar, se ele não melhorar negativo. Nunca removo.

Comment: Ainda por cima a [pergunta é dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/360355/7210). Quem fez review não review nada :P

Comment: Não a anterior. Poderia ter editado, mas ninguém é obrigado fazer isto. Não é praticamente igual, é tudo jogado em uma linha, falta uma linha, uma pontuação, é difícil de ler e compreender oque está escrito ali, e por isso provavelmente não quiseram editar, poderia até mudar a interpretação. O texto está claramente jogado e isto não é bom. Infelizmente parece ser senso comum que não é fácil entender o que está escrito ali para todos que entendem a língua portuguesa e suas regras básicas. E como não sendo boa um negativo não é exagerado, já a remoção é discutível.A remoção existe para ser usada

Comment: Maniero que eu saiba a remoção não é para esse tipo de coisas. Pelo menos foram as diretivas que me passaram no PL, que remoção só em caso de "lixo". De qualquer forma não é um comentário do AP ao próprio AP para esclarecimento. Me parece é que também nas reviews do site é tudo muito mecanizado já.

Comment: Vou até deixar o exemplo com uma simples edição.

Comment: Eu já discuti sobre isto. Existe a conversão em comentário que moderadores podem aplicar. Eu sempre defendi que a comunidade deveria poder fazer o mesmo. O que acaba acontecendo é que por falta da opção de converter em comentário as pessoas removem. Não é maluco que a comunidade tem poder de fazer o pior e não tem de fazer o melhor? Mas optaram assim e as discussões não foram para lugar algum. Fora isto leia meu texto novamente, eu disse que a remoção não estava certa e a resposta era ruim. Se eu achasse que estava certa eu teria removido de novo.

Comment: Maniero peço desculpa se entendi mal, mas fiquei com a ideia que vocês estava de acordo com a remoção. Para mim as respostas são idênticas. Falta apenas a formatação.

Comment: Eu alterei a resposta logo após restaurar, só mandei print dela como estava pra não ser incoerente de utilizar dados modificados ao fazer a reclamação

Answer (score 5):

Eu acho que este pode ser o típico caso de review mecanizada que quem vê lhe parece realmente uma resposta má e segue simplesmente quase sem analizar, até porque se repararem foi o próprio AP que respondeu, então nunca seria um comentário, não é?

Eu bem sei que não se deve olhar a quem responde para analisar o conteúdo, mas com um bocado de bom senso percebia-se que era o AP a dar a solução para o problema dele, ou seja, é efetivamente uma resposta.

Se fosse eu editava a resposta com a formatação, deixaria um comentário para o autor melhorar a resposta e se ele nada fizesse talvez um negativo. Afinal não é a politica do site tentar melhor em vez de apagar?! Tenho [um bom exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/54724/revisions) do que estou a dizer a funcionar bem (ver revisão 1 e 5 e os comentários). O tipico caso que uma resposta que até estava errada e se tornou numa resposta excelente. Vai acontecer com todas as respostas? Não, mas se tivéssemos apagado essa com toda a certeza não estaria no site.

Só por curiosidade, eu vou editar a resposta do AP e colocar só como código e vejam a diferença da outra resposta:

---

É só usar no lugar do

```
swapAdapter(adapter, true)
```

o

```
setAdapter(adapter)
```

As duas repostas são praticamente iguais, uma foi excluída a outra está com votação positiva. Estranho não?

Quanto a mim isto é um problema generalizado do site, e já não é de agora. Cada vez menos as pessoas se dão ao trabalho de tentar perceber e/ou editar o conteúdo que não esteja 100% explicito. Este é um bom exemplo disso mesmo ou se negativa ou (pior) se apaga o conteúdo sem um comentário sequer. Talvez as pessoas não lidem bem com comentários que pedem para melhorar, mas por uma vez que funcione já valeu a pena não acham?

---

PS: Como podem ver algumas frases que eu editei na minha resposta fizeram com que ficasse muito melhor e menos agressiva para quem fez a review. Uma edição ou um comentário podem fazer milagres ;)

Comment: A versão atual é mais compreensível e vendo a outra fica mais fácil ainda, mas na original era difícil entender o que estava dizendo ali, pode ser um detalhe bobo , mas que faz toda diferença para a resposta não ser boa, aí por ser simples demais as pessoas consideraram apenas um comentário. Esta forma é compreensível, mas ainda não é boa, "largada", a outra é caprichada, cuida dos detalhes.

Comment: Maniero continuo a não concordar com isso, você me dizer que a outra resposta está caprichada e cuida dos detalhes me deixa incrédulo. Se a diferença de uma resposta boa para uma má é a formatação, então algo está muito errado a meu ver. Ainda gostava de saber qual é a sua definição de caprichada e que cuida de detalhes. Se as respostas são praticamente iguais. Se está a falar da linha de código a mais, ela nem é necessária. Custa-me a entender esse seu critério, mas pronto cada um com a sua opinião.

Comment: Para mim a diferença de uma resposta normal e uma caprichada que cuida dos detalhes é a diferença da primeira revisão para a última [deste exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/54724/revisions). Na revisão 1 é uma resposta simples, na revisão 5 uma caprichada.

Answer (score 2):

As respostas já esclarecem a sua questão, mas, por ter participado da ação, quero esclarecer meu método.

---

Logo assim que comecei a participar da comunidade, achava que (como proposto em vários lugares aqui) era só chegar, apontar o "defeito" e dar uma solução. Sem mais!

Acontece que se alguém o fizer dessa forma, a resposta, ainda que não seja removida, vai ser alvo de *votedowns*. Não é a toa que as respostas mais bem recebidas são aquelas com textos imensos. Até mesmo dignas de um livro!

> "*não só mostram o código, mas também explicam porque aquilo funciona, qual o conceito por trás daquilo, porque do outro jeito não funciona, etc*" - [hkotsubo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo)

Quando bate na fila de análise, a resposta deve atender os critérios de quem está analisando baseando-se no padrão da comunidade.

[image: fila de análise]

Nós, ao analisarmos, acabamos "repetindo" aquilo que já foi feito conosco. Eu mesmo já fui alvo de votedowns e até pergunta fechada por conta disso. Hoje utilizo dos mesmos critérios para avaliar as publicações dos colegas. Ainda que isso acabe criando uma inimizade e as vezes até perseguição (é, acontece comigo frequentemente) simplesmente por tentar dizer ao colega: "*melhore sua publicação*".

> "*Denunciaram minha resposta*"

Acredito que, como no seu caso, a sua resposta não precisa ser **sinalizada** para cair na fila de análise. O próprio algoritmo do site identifica "pouco conteúdo" e joga lá para ser avaliada por um humano. O mesmo acontece com publicações de novos usuários...

Então, quando estivermos dispostos a responder alguma pergunta, é ideal que estejamos preparados para atender os critérios da comunidade e esclarecer a fundo o problema em questão...

Como o comentário na sua publicação diz: "*isso não fornece uma resposta à pergunta*". E pode ter certeza que eu jamais teria dado um voteup na resposta posterior, ainda que aceita.

E ainda que "solucione o problema", quem pergunta acaba "fazendo sem entender". Respostas tendem a ser esclarecedoras, objetivas, etc. <strike>Ignorando a questão de você ter respondido sua própria pergunta.</strike>

A pesar de tudo isso, pode acontecer de um dia você repetir ou encontrar algo semelhante e a comunidade receber bem. Como já mencionado, vale muito de quem está "avaliando" o conteúdo postado.