# Como faço pra ter uma pergunta de boa qualidade?

Tags: debate

Eu tenho um problema que sempre uso o *SOpt* pelo celular e as vezes aparecem caracteres do nada, e acontece que o *SOpt* trava o texto que estou respondendo.

Como faço pra ter resposta boas nesta comunidade? É errado usar imagens para mostrar um erro?

Muitas vezes me ofenderam e deram mal reputação porque usei imagens.

Se alguém tive educação, por favor, me responda.

Eu queria dizer que esta comunidade já acabou com 1000 dúvidas.

Comment: "Muitas vezes me ofenderam [...]", quando isso acontecer sinalize aos moderadores; tanto as perguntas, respostas e comentários possuem esta opção. Não toleramos nenhum tipo de ofensa na comunidade. Quanto às imagens, elas são excelentes como forma de **agregar** conteúdo, de forma a facilitar a explicação, exemplificar ou apenas descontrair de alguma forma. Ela não deve ser utilizada como parte principal da publicação, pois não será indexada por motores de buscas e muitos usuários não poderão vê-las (limitações da rede, por exemplo).

Comment: Uma maneira boa é ver [como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/75104) , [não entendo votos negativos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4948/75104), [como se portar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/38/75104) e [ask]

Comment: Os problemas de usar imagem em vez de texto estão explicados no [FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052). Claro que isso não é motivo para ofender (e caso aconteça, [sinalize para a moderação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), conforme já dito acima). Enfim, eu particularmente sempre gostei do Stack Overflow pelas respostas completas e detalhadas, que não apenas dão o código, mas explicam pq ele funciona. E [continuo achando](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7639/112052) que esse é o caminho para uma resposta ser boa.

Comment: Olá caro Maury. Tem certeza que lhe ofenderam? Ou foi apenas uma critica um pouco mais agressiva, que talvez tenha soado mal ou talvez você realmente não tenha interpretado bem o que foi dito? Downvote não é ataque pessoal, se fosse nem existira tal sistema, eu nunca vi suas postagens, ando um pouco afastado do site, mas se postou imagem ao invés de código é claro que o downvote é uma indicação que você tem que corrigir algo na sua pergunta. Observar como outras perguntas são feitas talvez seja um caminho.

Comment: **sobre imagens**, aqui estão os motivos que acredito serem os principais do porque postar imagens é algo **péssimo** para a comunidade: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635, não só sobre erros, mas códigos também.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento é certo chamar um pessoa de noob e de idiota? Eles me ofenderam até minha mãe. Eu não me importo com downvote. Eu estou falando dos usuário que fica votando aleatoriamente downvote. Uma vez em outra conta postei uma resposta,e do nada venho um mal educado me xingado,sendo que resolvi problema do dono da pergunta.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper usaram mesmo as palavras noob e idiota? Realmente foram raras a vezes que ouvi palavras assim no site, se foi provavelmente não foi por parte dos frequentadores e veteranos, provavelmente foi algum turista, mas se isso realmente ocorreu não se preocupe e nunca revide, sinalize para um moderador, eles são muito ativos e com certeza a pessoa sera punida. Provavelmente ocorreu uma vez so e foi so uma pessoa, agora se ocorreu mais de uma vez tem que ver o contexto, pq talvez a pessoa usou uma palavra como "iniciante" e você interpretou como outra coisa

Comment: @MauryDeveloper isto é grave e precisamos saber imediatamente onde ocorreu. Esta é uma comunidade onde exige-se respeito pelas pessoas.

Comment: @Maniero não adianta foi uma conta fake.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper não importa, nós precisamos tomar providências, você precisa nos informar sobre isso. Eu procurei nas suas atividades e não vi nada, mas não é fácil achar algo assim, então preciso da sua colaboração.

Comment: Foi em outra conta,e nem lembro o nome dele. Maniero isso já fez 1 mês,como vou lembrar? Eu era noob e não entendia nada. Se alguém hoje me fiz algo eu sempre sinalizo.

Comment: Se você não lembra não deve ter sido tão ofensivo assim, quem apanha nunca esquece. Eu acho estranho que ninguém mais sinalizou também, em geral sempre tem usuários lendo tudo e costumam sinalizar mesmo quando só envolvem outras pessoas. Que bom que não achou noob ofensivo. Você havia dito que "eles", parecia ser até mais que uma pessoa. Quanto à outra conta, se você tem outra podemos juntar as duas. Cuidado porque se usar duas contas pode entrar em situação que poderá gerar suspensão se elas interagirem.

Comment: @Maneiro A outra conta não uso mais.

Comment: Outro motivo para tentar evitar imagens, é para dar mais [acessibilidade ao site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2112/acessibilidade-do-site-em-termos-gerais/7414). Edit: Está no link que o Guilherme Nascimento postou sobre isso também.

Comment: Maury, já vi algumas postagens suas, principalmente de uns 5 dias pra cá. Só acho que você deve **tentar** ao máximo pegar o jeito do funcionamento do site, já que vc é usuário recém ingressado. Não sei a sua idade nem a sua formação, mas isso não importa muito, pois, o importante, na minha opinião e o que prezo bastante, é a qualidade do texto, seja ele o mais simples que for. Uma coisa que me chamou atenção nas suas postagens é o seu esforço em querer ajudar, isso é bom, mas não é tudo. É preciso unir conteúdo com qualidade.[...]

Comment: [...]e acho que vc ainda precisa pegar _o jeito_. Se você notar no texto desta pergunta que fez, me parece bem confuso e com muitos erros gramaticais. Acho assim, que se vc quer ser um bom profissional, busque aprimorar a sua redação, isso conta muito no mercado lá fora. Abs!

Comment: @Sam Meu português no ano passado era péssimo demais. Nesse ano tô lendo livros e lendo sobre a regra da gramática.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na minha experiência no site algumas boas práticas quase sempre resultam em boas perguntas, mas é claro há excessões pras esses guias.

- Pra mim o principal é que sua pergunta seja objetiva e tenha código. Uma boa pergunta é "estou tentando fazer isso, estou tomando tal erro e esse é meu códgio". Quase sempre uma pergunta sem código é uma pergunta ruim pois dificulta muito pra quem vai tentar responder.
- Outro ponto a se pensar quando se faz uma pergunta é que diferente de outros foruns o StackOverflow tem como objetivo ser extrememanete técnico e para cada pergunta ser um artefato de referencia para outras pessoas. Sendo assim evite cordialidades como "bom dia, meu nome é diego...", também pense se sua pergunta é algo especifico do seu projeto ou algo que pode ajudar outras pessoas. Vira e mexe vejo perguntas que parecem enunciado de uma questão e ninguem vai responder isso. Com isso em mente também tente fazer perguntas atemporais se possível.
- Fora isso é seguir o manual de como não fazer perguntas principalmente evitar imagens e links externos a não ser que seja um stackblitz ou algo do tipo com o seu código.
- Também uma pergunta bem feita não pode ser uma pergunta preguiçosa. Tente escrever bem e claramente, pesquise antes de fazer uma pergunta e deixe claro se possível com código o que vc tentou. "Estou tentando fazer isso mas não consigo" é uma péssima pergunta pois parece que vc não tentou nada principalmente se não tiver código.

[Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas)

Comment: Eduardo odeio link de código,porque eu sou celular,maioria deles é muito pesado. Imagem é ruim,pos quero copiar o texto do texto pra responder.

Comment: Vale lembrar que um stackblitz é diferente pra algo como aqui está o link do meu repositório. Ninguem vai baixar um projeto, baixar as dependecias e rodar pra ver o erro.

Comment: Você teve um erro de sintaxe no português,posso dar downvote(brincadeira kkkk). `estou tentando fazer isso, estou tomando tal erro e esse é meu códgio`